# C# Break point, selection of frame kinect v2

Tags: c#, frame, kinect, data-acquisition

I m using the sdk 2, sample face basic.(C# programming)
I would like to insert a breakpoint or flow only a predefinite number of frame, or use a predefinite frame as image for analyze it.
Where and how can I get in the code to do this?
I am in acquisition frame function, but I do not know how to act to influence the frame to be processed.

```
using (FaceFrame faceFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
        {
            if (faceFrame != null)
            {
                // get the index of the face source from the face source array
                int index = this.GetFaceSourceIndex(faceFrame.FaceFrameSource);
                // check if this face frame has valid face frame results
                if (this.ValidateFaceBoxAndPoints(faceFrame.FaceFrameResult))
                {
                // store this face frame result to draw later
                // here i can extract the feature of face of all frame   
                    this.faceFrameResults[index] = faceFrame.FaceFrameResult;
            }
```

I would like to want to extract the feature of one particular of some particular frame.

Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [`Debugger.Break()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx) method, given by the `System.Diagnostic` namespace, wherever you need.